# Django aggregate ForeignKey hierarchy

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-aggregation

Let's say I have the models `Foo`, `Bar` and `FooBar`. `Bar` has a ForeignKey reference to `Foo`. `FooBar` has a ForeignKey reference to `Bar`. Given a `Foo`-object, how do I most efficiently gather all related `FooBar` objects? I don't like using this:

```
foobars = []
for bar in foo.bar_set.all():
    for foobar in bar.foobar_set.all():
        foobars.append(foobar)
```

Comment: You want to get all foobars for one foo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do it by spanning relationship

```
foobars = FooBar.object.filter(bar__foo=foo)
```